# Servlet filter invoke not on default port

Tags: web-services, tomcat, servlets, cxf

i have a small webapp built on CXF for REST operations and Tomcat to host a *.war file. Recently i expose static content via Tomcat on port 8080, and REST operations via CXF on port 9015.
Now i try to expose everything (REST API and html pages) through CXF port 9015. I serve static content on embedded Jetty (port 9015), but servlet filter defined in web.xml refuses to work when i try to get my index.html page from localhost:9015/index.html (when i make request on localhost:8080/index.html--filter works):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

How can i make this LoginFilter intercept my request when i go on 9015 port?
Any help highly appreciated.